# Ruby escaping regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

What does it mean when something has escaped a regular expression?

I'm not sure I quite understand what this means. Can someone give an explanation and examples please?

Comment: where have you seen the line ? from there can you copy and paste a code here ?

Comment: "In addition, path names in standard maze files containing escaped quotes (e.g., \"path1\") must be converted to path names with normal quotes (e.g., "path1") in the standard maze file output. "

Comment: If any path names contain escaped quotes, they must be converted to normal quotes. For instance the names path\"3\" and \"path4\" should be converted to path"3" and "path4" in the simple maze file format output.

Comment: I don't think `escape a regular expression` means anything valid. I think that phrase does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a regular expression, certain characters such as `.+?{}[]` have meaning. They are called [metacharacters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter).

You can escape them in Ruby with the [.escape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) method:

```
irb(main):001:0> Regexp.escape('*.?')
=> "\\*\\.\\?"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more context it's hard to say what that means exactly.  My best guess though is that they are saying they have turned a character that is special to regular expressions into it's plain character equivalent.

That is to say, `/foo.bar/` will match "fooXbar" and "fooZbar".  `/foo\.bar/` won't match those however and will only match "foo.bar".

`.` - match any single character

`\.` - match a period.

Answer (score 0):

Just escape [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) spec chars `[](){}.*+-<>:?^$|\/`:

```
'a[](){}.*+-<>:?^$|\/'.gsub(/[\[\]()\{}.*+\-<>:?^$|\/]/) {|m| "\\#{m[0]}" }
# => "a\\[\\]\\(\\)\\{\\}\\.\\*\\+\\-\\<\\>\\:\\?\\^\\$\\|\\\\/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comment:  `For instance the names path\"3\" and \"path4\" should be converted to path"3" and "path4"`

Unescaping quotes only using regex:

find:  `(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)\\(")`
replace `\1\2`

Explained:

```
 (?<! \\ )              # Not an escape behind us
 (                      # (1 start)
      (?: \\\\ )*            # Optional many double escapes (an even amount)
 )                      # (1 end)
 \\                     # Single escape
 ( " )                  # (2), A double quote
```